# (C#) Selenium: How to convert an IWebElement to String?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#

> Error CS0029 Can not implicitly convert type OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement em string

What I am doing is:

```c#
// Declaration of the global variable portalweb
public string portalweb;

// function to click on button
public void btnCcnpj_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://...");

    IWebElement secondRow = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("tr:nth-of-type(2)"));
    IWebElement client = secondRow.FindElement(By.CssSelector("td:nth-of-type(3)"));
    IWebElement portal = secondRow.FindElement(By.CssSelector("td:nth-of-type(4) a"));
    IWebElement nomeDoPortal = secondRow.FindElement(By.CssSelector("td:nth-of-type(5)"));

    portalweb = portal;
}

// TextBox where the HTML data should appear (in this example the number: 1149)
private void txbPortal_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txbPortal.Text = portalweb;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A web element can have many attributes. You're using one of it's attributes to find it (it's `class`). It can also have an `ID`, a `href`, a `value`, any number of attributes depending on the type of web element. Your portal element seems to be an anchor (`a`). An anchors `text` attribute is a string. So if you `getText()` of this element you should have what you're looking for.

Comment: I can not put my code together, could you help me?
I'm a beginner and I do not know much yet.

Comment: Here is my HTML code:
https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/37202/c-selenium-how-to-extract-information-from-html-and-write-to-a-variable

Comment: @Ronison Matos you need `portalweb = portal.Text;` or `portalweb = portal.GetAttribute("text");` instead of `portalweb = portal`. `portal` is an IWebElement while `portalweb` is a string, two different types. So you need the text attribute of the IWebElement as that one is a string as well.