# How to select the second tr of my HTML?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#, selenium-webdriver-c#

The code below works but it only selects the first `tr`:

My HTML:

```html
<script>if(''!='') { document.Form2.endereco_ip.value='';}</script> 
<div style="font-size: 10pt; font-weight: bold">Listagem
</div>
<hr style="height: 1px">
<table width="100%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse">
  <tbody>
    <tr style="background-color: #E8E8E8">
      <td width="1%">&nbsp;
      </td>
      <td width="5%">
        <b>Rede
        </b>
      </td>
      <td width="5%">
        <b>Tipo
        </b>
      </td>
      <td width="5%">
        <b>Portal
        </b>
      </td>
      <td width="20%">
        <b>Nome do Portal
        </b>
      </td>
      <td width="10%">
        <b>Franqueador
        </b>
      </td>
      <td width="10%">
        <b>Ambiente
        </b>
      </td>
      <td width="10%">
        <b>Endereço BD
        </b>
      </td>
      <td width="15%">
        <b>Endereço Páginas
        </b>
      </td>
      <td width="5%">
        <b>Release
        </b>
      </td>
      <td width="5%">
        <strong>Administrador</strong>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td bgcolor="green" title="xxx">
      </td>
      <td>Nome_emp
      </td>
      <td>Cliente
      </td>                 
      <td>
        <a target="_blank" title="Descricao." href="#">1149</a>                                                     
      <td>Nome_emp 
        <b> - Empresa: 19; 
        </b>
      </td>
      <td>9841 - Nome - empresa
      </td>
      <td>Micro (95%)
      </td>
      <td>LINK.COM.BR
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="http://#" target="_blank"><font color="blue">http://#
          </font></a>
      </td>
      <td>2.0
      </td>
      <td class="style1">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My Selenium code:

```c#
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://...");
IWebElement secondRow = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("table tr:nth-of-type(2)"));
portalweb = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("td:nth-of-type(4)")).Text;
txbPortal.Text = portalweb;
```

Comment: What result does your code give you?

Comment: When I run it returns the title "Portal" being that it should return the value "1149" which is in the second tr.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To add explanation to what you have already figured out. The problem was that with this line you correctly acquired the second row:

```c#
IWebElement secondRow = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("table tr:nth-of-type(2)"));
```

but with the next piece of code, you did not get the `4th cell` of the second row, but the **first** `4th cell` of the DOM and that starts from the first row, the header. That is why it has returned "portal".

```c#
portalweb = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("td:nth-of-type(4)")).Text;
```

so instead of the previous line you should do what you have already figured out:

```c#
portalweb = secondRow.FindElement(By.CssSelector("td:nth-of-type(4)")).Text;
```

run the second `FindElement` on the second row, and not on the whole DOM again.

Comment: Why css is used in this case? any specific reason? I think we can achieve it by Xpath or filndelementsby tagname and 2nd element from list. Please clarify

Comment: @SQA_LEARN The OP used css I just used his original code in the answer. Anyway the OP used css because it was suggested to him in his other question: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/37202/c-selenium-how-to-extract-information-from-html-and-write-to-a-variable I specially suggested the same as you, `FindElements` and xpath.

Answer (score 2):

I made the following change and it worked:

```
portalweb = secondRow.FindElement(By.CssSelector("td:nth-of-type(4)")).Text;
```